# notifyListeners() running on a loop

Tags: android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

Notifylisteners is continuously running on a loop

```
Future<void> fetchAndSetMeal() async {
final List<Meal> loadedProducts = [];
var data = await DataBaseHelpers.getData();
if (data.documents == null) {
  return;
}
List<DocumentSnapshot> list = data.documents;

list.forEach((document) async {
  var url = await DataBaseHelpers.getImageUrl(document.documentID);

  loadedProducts.insert(
      0,
      Meal(
          id: document.documentID,
          category: document.data['category'],
          description: document.data['description'],
          title: document.data['title'],
          price: document.data['price'],
          imgUrl: url));
});
await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 300));
print(loadedProducts[0]);
notifyListeners();
_items = loadedProducts;
```

}
}

//The print and network call statements are also running twice as opposed to //just once for every call. notifyListeners() is running on a loop;

Comment: I believe the problem is with your async forEach declaration. Try this instead: `await Future.forEach(list, (document) async {///your block of code here});`.

Comment: how did you call fetchAndSetMeal ? inside initState or inside build method ?

Comment: I was getting frustrated by manually doing this so I used Streams instead. Works like a charm now. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You got your `notifyListeners` inside `foreach` loop. Move it outside

Comment: Add some code to make it look like an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: Still, the same problem was arising